# Swift App Development Error - Thread 1 Signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sigabrt

I know this question has been asked multiple times before, but using all the information gained from their answers, my project still crashes!

I am learning App Development, using the iBook Intro to App Development with Swift, in Apple's Everyone Can Code series. I am using Chapter 17.3, which is Multiple Actions and Outlets, and I am following the code and videos ***exactly*** as shown, however, when I flick the first switch, the View object should turn red, but it doesn't, and flicking the two other switches crashes the app, with the error `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`. The console error is this:

```
2018-09-06 18:29:35.503697+1000 ColorMix[2654:141233] -[ColorMix.ViewController greenSwitch:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89a4c09110
2018-09-06 18:29:35.515103+1000 ColorMix[2654:141233] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ColorMix.ViewController greenSwitch:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89a4c09110'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001113a81e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f9ce031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111429784 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000111d5e6db -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 295
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011132a898 ___forwarding___ + 1432
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011132a278 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000111b313e8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000111cac7a4 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000111cacac1 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001127edea0 -[UISwitchModernVisualElement sendStateChangeActions] + 73
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001121af9d3 -[UISwitchMVEGestureTrackingSession _sendStateChangeActionsIfNecessary] + 63
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001127ee62c -[UISwitchModernVisualElement _handleLongPressWithGestureLocationInBounds:gestureState:] + 760
    12  UIKit                               0x000000011212854f -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 57
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000112131324 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 109
    14  UIKit                               0x000000011212eb6c _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 307
    15  UIKit                               0x000000011212ddc0 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 859
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000112112e24 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1329
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001121128a7 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 484
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001121119a9 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 281
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000111ba77ab -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4064
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000111b4b310 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    21  UIKit                               0x000000011248c6af __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2796
    22  UIKit                               0x000000011248f2c4 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5949
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011134abb1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011132f4af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011132ea6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011132e30b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000115efea73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000111b30057 UIApplicationMain + 159
    29  ColorMix                            0x000000010f0c2a67 main + 55
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001147ec955 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here are screenshots of my ViewController and Main.storyboard files:

[image]
[image]

Also, after my app crashes, something weird happens: new outlets (filled dots) are created on lines 33 & 48, where there is nothing relating to outlets whatsoever.

Please let me know if you need any more information/code, I would appreciate all help!

Comment: Copy/paste code, not screenshot of code. Also, on the Storyboard, Select you ViewController, (The "View Controller"  between "View Controller Scene" and "View".) On the right panel, show us a screenshot of what you have when you select the last panel (Show the Connections Inspector). Did you had at first a method named `@IBAction func greenSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch)` or something like that?

Comment: Check in storyboard if it containing any unwanted IBActions attached to element.

Comment: Can you please share demo code with us

Comment: What do you mean demo code? The book code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

> [ColorMix.ViewController greenSwitch:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

means that you have created an IBAction named `greenSwitch` then deleted it , so try to remove it from the switch in IB , or create that action inside the VC

[image]

Comment: So should I delete the item in the green box you have highlighted?

Comment: Note, you should remove the "Value Changed" link, not the Referencing Outlet (it's not that clear in @Sh_Khan answer).

Comment: click the x to remove it